# Are there any Agamic temples outside the South?

Tags: agamas

In my experience, temples in the North are run more informally than Agamic temples in the South with a garbagriha that only the temple priests can enter and other regulations.

Are there temples outside the South that are run by strict Agamic rules?

Comment: yes there are in the north temples like that

Comment: Jagannath temple, Puri.